# Vue navigation with vue router: dynamic navigation items upon user selection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, navigation, vuetify.js, vue-router

I have a problem with my v-navigation drawer in vue. I create the individual menu items with v-for from the $router.options.routes as computed. There are menu items that should always be displayed (static) and there are menu items (dynamic/conditional) that should only be displayed after the user has made a corresponding selection with a v-select. I get the selection via mapState from the store, which is an array. My problem is that either only the static one or the other one works.

My approach was to filter the routes by the meta field entries with the array. Works very well, except that the static menu items do not appear in the result. If nothing is selected yet, array.fillter of course returns an empty array, so there are no menu items.

Routes example

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "login",
    component: () => import("../views/Login"),
    meta: {}
  },
  {
    path: "/typeone",
    name: "typeone",
    component: () => import("../views/typeone"),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
      display: false,        // static entry in naviagtion, should always be shown
      title: "typeone",
      icon: "mdi-cogs mdi-fw"
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/typetwo",
    name: "typetwo",
    component: () => import("../views/typetwo"),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
      display: true,        // dynamic entry in naviagtion, should be shown upon user selection
      title: "typetwo",
      icon: "mdi-home-group mdi-fw"
    }
  },
  ...
];
```

NavigationDrawer extract

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    ...
  >
    <v-list
      nav
      :dense="dense"
      v-for="(route, index) in computedRoutes"
      :key="index"
    >
      <core-navigation-item :routesData="route" />
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
import CoreNavigationItem from "./CoreNavigationItem";
import { mapState } from "vuex";
...
computed: {
    ...mapState({
      productionType: state => state.productionType
    // this ist the array from the user selection, eg: ["typeone", "typetwo", ...]
    }),
computedRoutes() {
      // show just the static entries
      return this.$router.options.routes.filter((route) => route.meta.display === false);

      // show the dynamic entries only
      // return this.$router.options.routes.filter(item => this.productionType.includes(item.meta.title));

      // and this does not work
      // return this.$router.options.routes.filter(item => this.productionType.includes(item.meta.title) && item.meta.display === false);
    }
```

I also tried to react upon changes on the selection array and alter the value of.meta.display.

> this.productionType.forEach((item) => this.$router.options.routes.find(val => val.meta.title === item).meta.display = false);

That works in computed and watch, but it needs a forced component reload in order to not show a menu item when user deselects.

I'm completely stuck here.  If anyone has an idea or a clue, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved. I mapped the selection items from schema in state and matched them with the actual selected items. Therefore i build a method in the navigation-drawer, getting the difference between selected items and selection items. Method is called in the computedRoutes and filtered upon meta fields value.

Code extract from NavigationDrawer

```
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      productionType: state => state.productionType,
      // selectable items
      items: state => state.schema.selectProductionType.items
    }),
    computedRoutes() {
      this.buildRoutes();
      return this.$router.options.routes.filter(
        route => route.meta.display === false
      );
    }
  },
  methods: {
    buildRoutes() {
      this.productionType.forEach(
        item =>
          (this.$router.options.routes.find(
            val => val.meta.title === item
          ).meta.display = false)
      );
      this.items
        .filter(item => !this.productionType.includes(item))
        .forEach(
          item =>
            (this.$router.options.routes.find(
              val => val.meta.title === item
            ).meta.display = true)
        );
    }
  }
```